# Having Issues Creating a Countdown Timer, which should start a new timer whenever the last timer ends(Snack Link Included!)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setinterval, use-effect

So I'm trying to create a timer that allows a user to: start, pause, and resume.

Also, I want the timer to start and run for 10 minutes, and once that's done, reset and run for 5 minutes, and then reset and run for another 10minutes and then stop.

The issue with my code is that the `clearInterval(interval)` isn't stopping the timer as expected when the conditions I'm looking for are met. The block of code is being accessed, and the console log within in runs, but my timer will keep going and will even let the minutes go negative :(

Here's the [snack](https://snack.expo.io/rk8cS1uAr) and code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'native-base';

const Timer = ({ timerStarted, toggleTimer }) => {
  const [minutes, handleMinutes] = useState('10');
  const [seconds, handleSeconds] = useState('00');
  const [secondsLeft, handleSecondsLeft] = useState();
  const [timerType, handleTimerType] = useState('1st'); // 2nd, 3rd

  console.log('timer type', timerType);

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;

    const timerEnded = minutes === '00' && seconds === '00';
    console.log('useEffect Upper Level', minutes, seconds);

    if (timerStarted && !timerEnded) {
      console.log('timer starting', minutes, seconds);
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        decrementClock();
      }, 100);
    }

    if (timerEnded && timerType === '3rd') {
      clearInterval(interval);
      // toggleTimer()
      console.log('DONE');
    }
    if (timerEnded && timerType === '2nd') {
      clearInterval(interval);
      handleMinutes('10');
      // toggleTimer();
      console.log('interval?', interval);
      handleTimerType('3rd');
      console.log('SECOND CONDITION');
    }

    if (timerEnded && timerType === '1st') {
      console.log('FIRST CONDITION');
      console.log('interval?', interval);
      clearInterval(interval);
      handleMinutes('05');
      // toggleTimer();
      handleTimerType('2nd');
    }

    if (!timerStarted) {
      console.log('paused?');
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timerStarted, seconds, minutes, secondsLeft, timerType]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let result = minutes * 60 + parseInt(seconds);

    timerStarted && handleSecondsLeft(result);
  }, [timerStarted]);

  const decrementClock = () => {
    let min = Math.floor(secondsLeft / 60);
    let sec = secondsLeft - min * 60;
    if (min < 10) {
      min = '0' + min;
    }
    if (sec < 10) {
      sec = '0' + sec;
    }

    handleMinutes(min);
    handleSeconds(sec);

    handleSecondsLeft(secondsLeft => secondsLeft - 1);
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text style={{ textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 40 }}>
        {minutes}:{seconds}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const TimerScreen = () => {
  const [timerStarted, handleTimerStarted] = useState(false);

  const toggleTimer = () => {
    handleTimerStarted(!timerStarted);
  };

  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Timer timerStarted={timerStarted} toggleTimer={toggleTimer} />
  </View>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {

}, [timerStarted, seconds, minutes, secondsLeft, timerType]);
```

Above code will be triggered every time when `timerStarted, seconds, minutes, secondsLeft, timerType` updated. I think it is not good because it will affect to your interval. You should separate your timer out.

You could use `useInterval` hooks in this tutorial https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

```
  useInterval(() => {
    decrementClock();
  }, timerStarted ? 1000 : null); // If timerStarted, run interval. Otherwise, reset it
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to fix it and have it work properly but the tutorial you linked should fix the delay issue I'm encountering as well. I'll get started on it. Thank you!